# How to remove a chrome.storage.onChanged Event Listener?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I think the documentation for `chrome.storage` API ([here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage)) is currently not clear. I'm using this code to add a listener:

```
chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function(changes, namespace) {
    for (key in changes) {
      var storageChange = changes[key];
      console.log('Storage key "%s" in namespace "%s" changed. ' +
                  'Old value was "%s", new value is "%s".',
                  key,
                  namespace,
                  storageChange.oldValue,
                  storageChange.newValue);
    }
  });
```

But how do i remove this listener? How to use the `chrome.storage.onChanged.removeListener()` method?

Answer (score 5):

The `chrome.storage.onChanged.removeListener` takes the listener function you added as an input, so to remove it later, you have to store the function in a variable. Following code will work:

```
var myListenerFunction = function(changes, namespace) {
    for (key in changes) {
      var storageChange = changes[key];
      console.log('Storage key "%s" in namespace "%s" changed. ' +
                  'Old value was "%s", new value is "%s".',
                  key,
                  namespace,
                  storageChange.oldValue,
                  storageChange.newValue);
    }
};

// Add listener
chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(myListenerFunction);

// Change value, will show output in console.log
chrome.storage.sync.set({'value': 'asd'});

// Remove listener
chrome.storage.onChanged.removeListener(myListenerFunction);

// Change value, will NOT show output in console.log as listener was removed
chrome.storage.sync.set({'value': 'asd123'});
```

Additional reading - The Events part of the Chrome extensions spec - https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events

Answer (score 2):

I didn't see chrome.storage.onChanged.removeListener in the page you provided.

Could you try assigning the callback function into a variable and pass it to AddListener. Then use that to remove

```js
var changeListener = function(changes, namespace) {
    for (key in changes) {
      var storageChange = changes[key];
      console.log('Storage key "%s" in namespace "%s" changed. ' +
                  'Old value was "%s", new value is "%s".',
                  key,
                  namespace,
                  storageChange.oldValue,
                  storageChange.newValue);
    }
 };


chrome.storage.onChanged.removeListener(changeListner);
```

Comment: It is listed as `Event.removeListener`. The `Event` here is `onChange` in this case.